# Setting akka TestKit default timeout in code

Tags: scala, akka

What's the correct way to set a default timeout for `TestProbe.expectNoMsg()` in code not in config?

I'm aware that I can define `akka.test.single-expect-default` in application.conf, but this applies to all tests in my module.  Or something like

```
ActorSystem(.., ConfigFactory.parseString("{akka.test.single-expect-default = 0}"))
```

in code works, but I'd expect to be able to set this timeout like

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(100 millis)
```

which I've seen references to but is not being recognized.

My test is

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MySuite extends path.FunSpec with Matchers {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("MySuite")

    val probe = new TestProbe(system)

    describe ("timeout") {
        println("Waiting..")
        probe.expectNoMsg()
        println("Waited")
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. But you can create your own Decorator for `TestProbe` which can hold an instance of `TestProbe` and have an `expectNoMsg()` method with an implicit parameter for the timeout. Or you can simple use `def expectNoMsg(max: FiniteDuration)` where needed with the timeout specified explicitly.

Comment: I agree with @SergiyPrydatchenko that you should first try and use the  `def expectNoMsg(max: FiniteDuration)` method instead.  If that doesn't work for you then you can pimp `TestProbe` with an implicit class to provide the behavior you seek.  In fact, I think the above should be added as an answer with a code example of the pimping.

Comment: @cmbaxter `expectNoMsg(Zero)` is what I'm  was using, and it works fine.  It's just surprising that since testkit provides a no-arg `expectNoMsg()`, I can't customize the timeout except through the `Config` approach.

Answer (score 3):

you want to set

```
akka.test.single-expect-default
```

in your config

Comment: Thanks, but I mention in the post why that's not idealm.